# Header File being included twice

Tags: c, visual-studio, compiler-errors, header-files

I am relatively new to C (as I don't want to use C++, or at least just yet) and I'm not sure how to fix my include error I am having.

I have a header file containing the constant value of 1000 and is called Test.

```
const int Test = 1000;
```

I have this file included in 2 files - Myfile.c and Myfile2.c each including the file as such:

```
#include "MyHeader.h"
```

My project will not build/compile and as I have found out it is including the header twice which is not allowed as I am declaring my variable "Test" twice. Upon research I found this on Wikipedia: http://bit.ly/10wPraP

I used this "Include Guard"

Example:

```
#ifndef MY_HEADER
#define MY_HEADER
 const int Test = 1000;
#endif
```

and I have also tried the pre-processor(?) command pragma once.

```
#pragma once
```

However, my program still will not build. I now get error saying that the varibale "Test" is already defined in MyFile.obj.

I thought this might be a Visual Studio-ism as I am using that but both my 2010 Express C++ and VS2003 Professional wont build this. I have tried cleaning the project within Visual Studio and I am not sure what else to do.

Am I being very silly and missing something obvious here and that is why it isn't work?

I am used to C# and "using" with namespaces rather than includes. May my setting on VS to only compile C code be effecting this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Include guards have nothing to do with it. You need to separate the declaration from the definition and have only *one* definition (this is called the "one definition rule", ODR):

**header.h:**

```
extern const int n;
```

**one source file:**

```
#include "header.h"

const int n = 1000;
```

**all other source files:**

```
#include "header.h"
```

Comment: Thank you! I shall accept this as the answer once I can. I thought the "extern" was a C++ OO keyword and didn't think to try it...

Comment: @Kerrek, This really confused me. I completely understand what you're saying about the ODR, but in my own solution, I have a "defines" header that is essentially a bunch of constants defined as `const int x = 12345;`. This header is included in many places. Why does it compile for me? Is C++ different in this regard? (VS2010 btw)

Comment: @AK4749: In C++, namespace-scope `const` variables have internal linkage (they're implicitly `static`).

Comment: @KerrekSB excellent, good to know this before I took this happy accident as writ. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @AK4749: Yeah, this is quite a useful feature. For example, for a `const int n = 10;`, the compiler may well just substitute the value literally where it is used and never actually store the object *anywhere* (e.g. unless you try to take its address). Since every file that includes the header sees the same value, this is just as correct, and often preferable...

Answer (score 3):

**Useful Reference:**

- Wikipedia on the `extern` keyword: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_variable
- Wikipedia on the One Definition Rule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule

The problem is with the way that header files are processed when you #include them: Header files are literally copied and pasted into the body of your C files. This means that Myfile.c and Myfile2.c both have their own declarations of an int named Test - essentially creating two different versions of the one variable. The linker then complains about having two different variables with the same name.

The solution is to put the `const int Test = 1000;` in one of your C files, and to add `extern const int Test;` to MyHeader.h. This way, the variable is declared only once, and all files are aware of the one variable because the `extern` directive tells them that another file has the variable `Test` they are looking for.

**MyHeader.h**

```
extern const int Test;
```

**Myfile.c** (for instance)

```
#include "MyHeader.h"
...
const int Test = 1000;
```

**Myfile2.c**

```
#include "MyHeader.h"
...
<use Test>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is correct.  You have two source files that are *defining* `Test`.  You should only define this once.  Since header files get included all over the place, they should generally only *declare* variables, not *define* them.  e.g.

header:

`const int Test;`

Exactly one c file:

`const int Test = 1000;`

Answer (score 0):

Define that variable in any one of the `.c` file and declare that as extern in the header files.

```
#ifndef MY_HEADER
#define MY_HEADER
 extern const int Test;
#endif
```

In `Myfile.c` define the variable

```
const int Test = 1000;
```